# Erro de execução em switch

Tags: c, switch

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
int n1, n2, operacao, soma, sub, mult;  
float div;  
    printf("Escolha a opecaracao que deseja realizar: "); 
    scanf("d", &operacao);

    switch(operacao)
    {       
        case 1: '+';
            printf("\nInsira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
            printf("\nInsira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
            soma = n1+n2;
            printf("\n%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, soma);
        break;  

        case 2: '-';
            printf("\n Insira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
            printf("\n Insira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
            sub = n1-n2;
            printf("\n %d - %d = %d", n1, n2, sub);
        break;

        case 3: '*';
            printf("\n Insira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
            printf("\n Insira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
            mult = n1*n2;
            printf("\n %d X %d = %d", n1, n2, mult);    
        break;  

        case 4: '/';
            printf("\n Insira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
            printf("\n Insira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
            div = n1/n2;
            printf("\n %d / %d = %.2f", n1, n2, div);
        break;      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: o que a operação está fazendo na frente do case? já tentou remover `'+';` ?

Comment: O programa compila com a linha ` scanf("d", &operacao);` ? Ou mesmo fazer o `switch` com um `int` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos erros apresentados é que está pedindo a [formatação errada no `scanf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Na verdade acho que queria pedir o caractere da operação e não um número, então mudei isso também. E a sintaxe do `case` está bem errada é só `case` e o valor que está comparando e `:`, mais nada. Aproveitei e reduzi o escopo das variáveis e eliminei o que era desnecessário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    char operacao;
    printf("Escolha a opecaracao que deseja realizar: "); 
    scanf("%c", &operacao);
    switch (operacao) {       
    case '+':
        int n1, n2;
        printf("\nInsira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
        printf("\nInsira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
        printf("\n%d + %d = %d", n1, n2, n1  +n2);
    break;
    case '-':
        int n1, n2;
        printf("\n Insira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
        printf("\n Insira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
        printf("\n %d - %d = %d", n1, n2, n1 - n2);
    break;
    case '*':
        int n1, n2;
        printf("\n Insira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
        printf("\n Insira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
        mult = n1*n2;
        printf("\n %d X %d = %d", n1, n2, n1 * n2);    
    break;
    case '/':
        int n1, n2;
        printf("\n Insira N1: "); scanf("%d", &n1);
        printf("\n Insira N2: "); scanf("%d", &n2);
        printf("\n %d / %d = %.2f", n1, n2, (float)n1 / n2);
    break;      
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/0qRlTC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/oynzrejf-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Syntax/Case.c).

Comment: O meu compilador dá erro ao definir a variavel dentro do `case`, é possivel fazer isso com compiladores mais recentes?
Deixe-me só corrigir um pequeno erro seu, `chat` em vez de `char`

Comment: Que raio de compilador dos anos 80 está usando hoje em dia? :) Quando vê um erro pode editar.

Comment: Tenho de atualizar meu compilador então haha

Comment: Meu compilador deu erro nesse novo código também haha. Uso o DEV++. Qual vocês usam?

Comment: DevC++ é uma bomba, ninguém deveria usar isto, qualquer outra coisa é melhor.